# Twitter @anywhere: Status POST programmatically? Avoiding the embedded Tweet Box and OAuth

Tags: ajax, twitter, oauth, tweets, twitter-anywhere

Long time Stack Overflow lurker here. I've found many solutions to my problems, but having spent a few days researching this I feel it's time to ask...

I have a site where I'd like to perform an ajax POST with the contents of a textarea as the status text. In other words, I want to make a custom Tweet Box that uses @anywhere to authenticate rather than OAuth.

The reasons I want to write a tweet box from scratch instead of using the one provided by Twitter are:

1. Capture onclick events to perform additional functions (the site
   could be considered a Web App - the tweet the user writes should be
   instantly placed in a ul with some other tweets)
2. Full customisability of the box (JQuery animations, @media queries
   etc.)
3. Percentage width (!!!)

I realise that I can achieve all of these by going down the OAuth route - however, the @anywhere protocol is really cool, and getting it working this way would minimise development time greatly.

Thanks for the help!
Nabil